# Remove duplicate nodes in different parents with same child value, based on other childs value

Tags: xslt

I'm struggling getting this done with XSLT :

I need to remove duplicate nodes from an XML but it's different from the usual, cause these nodes can be in different parents and I can't just delete the first occurence but there's a prioritization rule.

This is my INPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<Collection>
<AddedType>
<Type>
    <Name>BBBBBBB</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Iteration>3</Iteration>
</Type>
<Type>
    <Name>AAAAAAA</Name>
    <Status>Off</Status>
    <Version>3</Version>
    <Iteration>0</Iteration>
</Type>
<Type>
    <Name>CCCCCCC</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Iteration>1</Iteration>
</Type>
<Type>
    <Name>BBBBBBB</Name>
    <Status>Off</Status>
    <Version>4</Version>
    <Iteration>0</Iteration>
</Type>
</AddedType>
<ChangedType>
<Type>
    <Name>BBBBBBB</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>7</Version>
    <Iteration>2</Iteration>
</Type>
</ChangedType>
<UnchangedType>
<Type>
    <Name>AAAAAAA</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Iteration>0</Iteration>
</Type>
</UnChangedType>
<DeletedType>
<Type>
    <Name>XXXXXX</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>5</Version>
    <Iteration>1</Iteration>
</Type>
</DeletedType>
</Collection>
</xml>
```

Desired OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<Collection>
<AddedType>
<Type>
    <Name>CCCCCCC</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Iteration>1</Iteration>
</Type>
</AddedType>
<ChangedType>
<Type>
    <Name>BBBBBBB</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>7</Version>
    <Iteration>2</Iteration>
</Type>
</ChangedType>
<UnchangedType>
<Type>
    <Name>AAAAAAA</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Iteration>0</Iteration>
</Type>
</UnChangedType>
<DeletedType>
<Type>
    <Name>XXXXXX</Name>
    <Status>On</Status>
    <Version>5</Version>
    <Iteration>1</Iteration>
</Type>
</DeletedType>
</Collection>
</xml>
```

**Type** nodes can be in **AddedType ChangedType UnChangedType DeletedType**

**Status** can only be **On** or **Off** with  **On** > **Off**

**Version** is numeric, integer

**Iteration** is numeric, integer

As you can see in the example above, I need to have in OUTPUT only 1 occurence of every **Type** node with the same **Name** value, and it should be the one with the greater priority based on the following rule:

The complete key for choosing which one to keep is (Status).(Version).(Iteration) example:  ***Off.5.1 < Off.5.8 < Off.7.5 < On.0.0 < On.3.9***

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Are you restricted to using only xslt or you can use a any oop langugae?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to XLST, otherwise I've already done this with xmltables and reconstructing the xml later

Comment: are you using .net framework's XSLTCompiledTransform to execute the xslt?

Comment: I'm currently invoking Saxon from command line

Comment: You can add extension object using the saxon framework. you can then generate the node structure in .net code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to group all those `Type` elements by the `Name` and then sort each group by your various sort keys/priorities to output the first in descending sort order, wrapped by its original parent name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Collection">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*/Type" group-by="Name">
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:sort select="Status" order="descending"/>
                  <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(Version)" order="descending"/>
                  <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(Iteration)" order="descending"/>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                      <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                      </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTk I get the result

```
<xml>
   <Collection>
      <ChangedType>
         <Type>
            <Name>BBBBBBB</Name>
            <Status>On</Status>
            <Version>7</Version>
            <Iteration>2</Iteration>
         </Type>
      </ChangedType>
      <UnchangedType>
         <Type>
            <Name>AAAAAAA</Name>
            <Status>On</Status>
            <Version>2</Version>
            <Iteration>0</Iteration>
         </Type>
      </UnchangedType>
      <AddedType>
         <Type>
            <Name>CCCCCCC</Name>
            <Status>On</Status>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Iteration>1</Iteration>
         </Type>
      </AddedType>
      <DeletedType>
         <Type>
            <Name>XXXXXX</Name>
            <Status>On</Status>
            <Version>5</Version>
            <Iteration>1</Iteration>
         </Type>
      </DeletedType>
   </Collection>
</xml>
```

which seems to have the elements you present in your wanted output, lacking the order you have shown there. I am not sure what determines that order so you will need to explain that if the code needs to be adjusted and you can't do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks man, I really need to study xslt > 1.0... regarding the order of the types it's not important, just the parent's one matters and it's fixed (added, changed, unchanged, deleted) but I think I can achieve  that atleast :)